# Why is composition of identity and unary function not equal to the function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

[Chapter 5 of Dr. Frisby's Guide](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ch05.html#category-theory) asserts that identity of a unary function is the function itself. That is, the last line of the code below should return true.

However, I am getting 'false'. Why?

```
const compose = (...fns) => (...args) => 
    fns.reduceRight((res, fn) => [fn.call(null, ...res)], args)[0];
const id = x => x;
const f = x => x === 4;
console.log( compose(id,f) === f ); //false ??
```

Comment: Since the source that you link to claims that `compose(id, f) === compose(f, id) === f`, and since `===` in JavaScript does *not* support the notation `a === b === c` as a shorthand for `a === b && b === c` (rather, it just means `(a === b) === c`), I think it's clear that the source shouldn't be taken too literally as a description of how JavaScript actually is. (I'm not sure whether that's because the author didn't intend it to be taken literally, or whether (s)he simply messed up, but either way, the result is the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `compose(id,f) === f` actually means is `compose(id,f) (x) === f(x)`, that is the results of both expressions must be the same. However, since JS isn't referential transparent the `===` operator only works for primitive types as expected.

In order to compare two functions themselves both must yield the same output (codomain) for the same input (domain). This obviously only works for finite domains, provided that the domain is enumerable and the codomain is comparable. As a result of these constraints functions have no instance for equality.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might depend on the language that you're using. Most languages are not equipped with a way to establish 'algebraic' equality between functions, and are likely to compare functions via their 'pointer' or 'reference', even if such is abstracted away. As a result, since your composed function would be a different function altogether (albeit with the same behaviour), it might not return as equal.

This being said, you can probably test it by having a set of input and running both functions on it, checking the equality of the output.

Comment: This is JS and testing the compositions gives expected results. That is... compose(id,f), compose(f,id) and f itself return same results on any argument. However, the book referred expects algebraic equality to hold in JS.

Comment: Ah, yeah I thought it might be JS. JS would compare the functions via their reference, and thus they would not be 'equal'. Do note that oftentimes in programming languages, mathematical equality is not the same as the contextual equality within the language.

Comment: Note that in JavaScript, functions are objects; you can even set random properties on them if you want. So even if JavaScript could somehow tell that two function objects had identical behavior *when called as functions*, it would still make sense for `===` to report that they are distinct objects.